# Blazor CSS isolation doesn't override Bootstrap styles

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

The name of my component is Account.razor

This line works fine inside the .razor component

```
<style>
    .tooltip-inner {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

But when creating the Account.razor.css and putting the same code the tooltip does not change the background color.

Comment: Can you provide some more of your `.razor` file that includes your tooltip?  If you have subcomponents, you may be encountering a situation where you need to use `::deep`.

Comment: I suggest you check the browser's dev tools to determine load order of your CSS. And to also check if the file in question has been loaded. Make sure to include a link to the CSS file within your Account.razor file.

Comment: A couple of things to check just in case: The browser sometimes heavily caches static files, so try forcing a reload with ctrl-f5 to clear the cache. Also, and this may be a silly question, but you're not including the "<style>" elements in the .css file, are you?

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  I upgraded from 3.1 to 5.0, and I noticed there were some comments in the upgrade notes about updating the CSS stuff, which I ignored.  I'm guessing that has something to do with it maybe?

Comment: @Marius When I enter the developer tools the tooltip does not have the override css code of my component. But other elements such as div, span, do have the override code that is in the same css file

Comment: I think I found the problem. When the tooltip element appears, its html code is added outside the div that the "page" class has, then it no longer has the scope of the component's css because it is outside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When the bootstrap tooltip element appears, its html code is added outside the div that the "page" class has, then it no longer has the scope of the component's css because it is outside of it

Answer (score 0):

Check the following (substitute you project name for mine (Blazor.Starter) :

1. Go to  *\Blazor.Starter\obj\Debug\net5.0\scopedcss\bundle* and check there's a css file generated for the project, and your CSS is included.  Note the id used `.page[b-l5khpg12dl] {..`
2. Check your referencing the CSS in your hosts/index file - `<link href="Blazor.Starter.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
3. Examine the html and classes in the browser and make sure you can see the project CSS file and the ID's for the Html generated by your component are the same.  If not Clean and Rebuild the project/library.

Comment: The file you mentioned in (1) exists, there is the file with the respective css code of my component.
There is also the css reference in the header of the _host.cshtml, I also tried putting it at the beginning of my component but it does not work either.
Fun fact, I can override some classes, like div, span, and others, but not the bootstrap components.
As I mentioned at the beginning. it works only by placing the styles inside the component.

Comment: The div elements to which I overridden have the code from the file "b-yl7tycy5rc" but the tooltip element does not have it, the two overrides are found in the same css file

Comment: I think I found the problem. When the tooltip element appears, its html code is added outside the div that the "page" class has, then it no longer has the scope of the component's css because it is outside of it